# Is renderscript can be use in jni code?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, renderscript

I saw a demo about **RenderScript**. Look at this [Render Script Demo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/ee6f190/java/tests/HelloComputeNDK).

It uses RenderScript in a JNI code. When I tried to use this method in my app, then AS report some errors.So I want to know if RenderScript be used in the JNI? If yes, how? Is this method faster than one used in java?

Comment: adding hyper link properly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used in C/C++ code, but you have to tell Android Studio that you wish to build RS code for native rather than Java.  You should be able to enable the gradle option `renderscriptNdkModeEnabled` to turn this on:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptNdkModeEnabled true
    }
}
```

That should enable AS to build your RS files for use by native code rather than Java.  It's a one or the other thing - you can't build them for both Java and native code.

Comment: i add the "renderscriptNdkModeEnabled true" in the gradle file. But i also can not include the head file: RenderScript.h in the jni. And i find that there is no any head file about the RenderScript in the path: Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-22/arch-arm/usr/include.

Comment: Looks like support for RS in the NDK was silently removed a while back: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/7.  No ETA on when it will be back in.